# ReactiveVar not working as expected in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using a reactive-variable in my Meteor app to show different content based on a user action.

Code looks like this:

home.js

```
Template.home.onCreated( function() {
    //toggles 'thank you' on home template for contact
    this.showForm = new ReactiveVar( false );
});
```

home.html

```
{{#if showForm }} 
                    Some form
                    {{else}}
                    Thank you message.
                        </header>
                    {{/if}}
```

Right now, the variable is not changing the content that is being shown.  No matter what I change it to, it shows the "Some form" content.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

You can't access reactive vars directly from the blaze template. You have to use a helper to do it. Add this code to your home.js:

```
Template.home.helpers({
  showForm: function() {
    return Template.instance().showForm.get();
  }
});
```